# Assign Sort Order of Product in Category with Catalog Flat Enabled

Tags: catalog, flat-catalog, flat

Hello I'd like to Assign Sort Order of Product in Category with Catalog Flat Enabled, is there a workaround to let this custom method I've created work without calling the admin store?
Right now trows exception. I've already solved calling

```
Mage::app('admin'); 
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

but I would like to avoid that because is messing up the router after I save redirecting me to the admin area.

I've also tried to add at the beginning:

```
Mage::register("isSecureArea",1);
```

and at the end of the method:

```
 Mage::unregister("isSecureArea");
```

but without success.
This is the method:

```
 public function assignCategories($category_ids, $productId){
    $position = 120;
    try {
        $api = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api');
        foreach ($category_ids as $category_id) {
            $api->assignProduct($category_id, $productId, $position);
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        Mage::log($ex, null,"Error.log");

    }
}
```

many thanks.